# Why does console.log behave like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

On the node.js interpreter:-

```
console.log("A newline character is written like \"\\ n \".");
//output is:-
// A newline character is written like "\ n ".
```

But when you simply enter this in the node.js interpreter:-

```
"A newline character is written like \"\\ n \"."
// it prints out:-
//'A newline character is written like "\\ n ".'
```

Does anybody now why this happened?
Just curious to know more about node.js
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: May be it is because when a string is parsed by the compiler. It behaves differently in the both cases. @azero0 .
But it gives the same output in pure-Javascript.
Nice check, may be the compiler does not parse the string datatypes as same as compared to the console.log()'s string. Good Question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When ***logging*** a string, it gets fully parsed and every character gets escaped, and that's ok, it is the expected behavior.

Nonethless, ***displaying* a string (not *logging*), the interpreter tries to show it in the simplest possible form.** This will also avoid any misunderstanding for the user who's looking at it. So, basically:

- Displaying `"\"hi\""` will show `'"hi"'`, because you can write a double quote inside a single quote delimited string without escaping it, and it's much easier to read.
- Displaying `'\'hi\''` will show `"'hi'"`, for the same reason.
- Displaying `"\"hi\", 'hey'"`, with both single and double quotes, will **force the interpreter to show you the original string** (in the same form you created it), because **there's no way to display it wothout escaping either the single or the double quotes**, so it can only be shown as `"\"hi\", 'hey'"`.

Try it by yourself:

```
var a = "\"hi\", 'hey'";
> "\"hi\", 'hey'"

var b = "\"hi\"";
> '"hi"'

console.log(a + ", " + b);
> "hi", 'hey', "hi"
```

Comment: I think I ran into this in an Angular app - was running Node 10.x.x and noticed the main.js file hash was different, so after un-minifying and comparing with one built on someone else's PC, it had added a backslash in the angular compiler source code. I updated to Node 12.x.x and the problem went away and the hash matches again! Is this kind of thing typical?