# backslash inserted into string before single quote, Node v8.11.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm following along with "Eloquent Javascript: Chapter 7 Project: A Robot" and having a problem with a backslash being inserted into my strings when using *NODE v8.11.4*. These backslashes do *NOT* appear when I run the code in Chrome's console.

Is there a way to prevent these backslashes from being inserted?

**The Code:**

```
const roads = ["Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin", "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall", "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall", "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm", "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm", "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop", "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"];

let edgeMap=edges.map(r=>r.split("-"))
console.log(edgeMap)
```

output using Node:

```
[ [ 'Alice\'s House', 'Bob\'s House' ],
  [ 'Alice\'s House', 'Cabin' ],
  [ 'Alice\'s House', 'Post Office' ],
  [ 'Bob\'s House', 'Town Hall' ],
  [ 'Daria\'s House', 'Ernie\'s House' ],
  [ 'Daria\'s House', 'Town Hall' ],
  [ 'Ernie\'s House', 'Grete\'s House' ],
  [ 'Grete\'s House', 'Farm' ],
  [ 'Grete\'s House', 'Shop' ],
  [ 'Marketplace', 'Farm' ],
  [ 'Marketplace', 'Post Office' ],
  [ 'Marketplace', 'Shop' ],
  [ 'Marketplace', 'Town Hall' ],
  [ 'Shop', 'Town Hall' ] ]
```

Comment: Maybe related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191951/why-does-console-log-behave-like-this

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew! I hadn't noticed this behavior of console.log before.

Answer (score 1):

No backslashes are getting inserted—that’s a feature of the `console.log` function. It makes it possible to read in the value as printed out.

Try saying:

```
edgeMap[0][0] == "Alice's House";
```

That should return `true`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this interesting "fun fact" more about console.log(). You're right, that the value is not actually being stored with the slash.  Something new for me to keep in mind :)